# Proximity tap in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, nfc, proximity

I'm trying to detect nearby devices using NFC or RFID from within a WPF application.

Microsoft's proximity API seems to be the right way to go:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465221.aspx

Unfortunately, I see no way to get it running inside a WPF application (or any other Desktop Technology that is). All examples refer to Microsoft store apps only.

From within a WPF application I cannot reference the Namespace

```
using Windows.Networking.Proximity;
```

Is it just a reference that I am missing? Is it possible to use the proximity API from a WPF application at all?

Comment: Just in case it matters: I'm using VS2013 on Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a sample project using the proximity API from within a WPF application:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/NFC-Editor-529ccda6

There is also a short tutorial included on how to use WinRT API's in WPF applications.

The basic steps:

- Manually add a `<TargetPlatformVersion>8.0</TargetPlatformVersion>` line to the csproj file
- Back in Visual Studio, add a reference to Windows/Core/Windows to the project references
- Add a reference to the Windows Runtime assemblies to the project.

See above given link for details.

Comment: How did you add proximity namespace to the project?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the `Windows.Networking.Proximity.ProximityDevice` class is *not* available in WPF Applications. If you look on the [`ProximityDevice` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.proximity.proximitydevice.aspx) page on MSDN, you'll see that it is part of the Windows.Phone API:

[image]

The monitor image next to the phone image also leads me to believe that it is available for Windows Store Apps too. I'm guessing that (at present at least) the vast majority of desktop computers won't have any RFC hardware that could be used with this code and so that is why it is missing from the standard .NET dlls.

Answer (score 0):

[2020 is here]

Procedure to prepare your Console/WPF project to call UWP APIs (both are OK):

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance
- https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2019/09/30/windows-10-winrt-api-packs-released/

Heads up: You'll need to migrate the project from the `packages.config` management format to the `PackageReference` format

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference#migration-steps